# ADD instruction of docker not running on windows machine

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to execute docker file in which I have add commands

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.2-jre-slim


EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 4040

VOLUME /data

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dos2unix

# main application JAR
ADD target/service.jar app.jar
# wrapper that executes the JVM
ADD bin/run.sh run.sh
#add the ui dist folder
ADD target/static static


RUN dos2unix /run.sh && apt-get --purge remove -y dos2unix && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ADD bin/java-buildpack-memory-calculator-linux-3.9.0 memory-calculator

RUN chmod +x run.sh
RUN chmod +x memory-calculator


ENTRYPOINT exec ./run.sh
```

The first command works fine but second command ADD `target/static static` gives an error

```
ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder231151249/target/static: no such file or directory
```

The same command works on Mac os but not on windows. Not sure what is wrong with it?
The folder structure is

```
|
|
|-------Dockerfile
|-------target
          |
          |
          |----------static
                        |
                        |
                        |---------html,js files
```

Comment: Could you please add the code that is including the docker build command? Or do you execute it manually? When is that command executed? Are you sure the target folder exists during the time the docker build command is called?

Comment: Hi, Yes the target/static folder exists at the time of running this command.  I run it manually using docker build -t ui-serivce .

Comment: Okay sounds good. Could you additionally add your project structure please so that we can see where the Dockerfile, the target folder etc. is located? It seems to me like the target folder is not in the docker build context. Normally all files that are located in the path that you specify in the `docker build` command ( *.* in your case) are sent to the build context. Does a .dockerignore file exist in your project?

Comment: @user1298426 please list out the docker folder structure .

Comment: @codinghaus,@gks please find folder structure in the description. I don't have .dockerignore file

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `./target/static` to Dockerfile like:

```
# wrapper that executes the JVM 
ADD bin/run.sh run.sh 
#add the ui dist folder 
ADD ./target/static static
```

Also try using `COPY` command rather than add:

```
  # wrapper that executes the JVM 
    COPY  bin/run.sh run.sh 
    #add the ui dist folder 
    COPY ./target/static/ static/
```

and run docker command like:

```
docker build --no-cache ....
```

Try Adding this to Dockerfile

```
 RUN mkdir -p /target/static/
 # wrapper that executes the JVM 
 COPY  bin/run.sh run.sh 
 #add the ui dist folder 
 COPY ./target/static/ /target/static/
```

Build Test Result:

```
Step 5/5 : ADD ./target/static/ static
 ---> 712e06b2d81c
Successfully built 712e06b2d81c
Successfully tagged test:latest
```

Only other suggestions I have is check Line Endings and make sure you don't have an extra spaces in the file names like **ADD** target/static or space at end of static

are you wanting the `target/static/` files to be in `/static` in the container?
or ... 
in `/target/static` in the container

Comment: apparently adding  Copy giving me same issue. For run.sh it works with add but for static folder it throws same exception.

Comment: Step 9/14 : COPY ./target/static/ static/
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder050475127/target/static: no such file or directory

Comment: added complete docker file

Comment: should be `ADD ./target/static/ target/static/` without the. `/` I think it's looking for `static` to be a file not a directory

Comment: So I've built the image in every way mentioned above (including the original) and it hasn't failed (setup folder structure as shown above) the only way I can make it fail is if I remove the target directory from host

Comment: It's not an issue with dockerfile but with windows how it creates the folder. I created another issue for this.